# Perfect DB design for Transaction feature

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

In my current project i am working a feature where people will buy/sell each others products. So let's say User1 has two products and User2 has 1 product.

Now if User1 buys one product from User2. And User2 buys two products of User1 than we will have 3 transaction. In my previous projects i used to do query each time in the DB Table and get all_credit and all_debit and then do like

```
current_balance = all_credit-all_debit
```

But now i get to know it's very bad practice because if you have too much transaction it will slow down your system. Knowing that i have decided to create one extra field with each user table like available balance where i am updating and data after each transaction one user does. If it's a addition i add balance and for deviation vice versa. Also i am saving data in transaction table. Not sure even that's perfect solution for this.

But with this solution the issue raise for my next project is their i have some feature where the system needs to hold for 7/15 days. Like if User1 buy product of  User2,  User2 can only see these balance as available or can withdraw/use them after 15 days. In the mean time he can see like unavailable balance as well. But the question is how i can make these unavailable funds available after 7/15 days ? While i used to make query in the whole Table i could make query by date to get the available balance of current time.
One of the solution i got is using cronjob after every 6 hours. But now sure if can use some more advance DB technology/logic to do this or senior use. Which would give me much better perfect solution that cronjob. Or does cron would be better for me. Also what if in future i get a requirement where i might need to run cron each hour. So won't it be bad for performance by running that big query(with cron) each hour ?

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow. Please show us the schema for what you have so far. You don't seem to have the requirements clear, so worrying about "will slow down your system" is what we call 'premature optimisation'. Don't do that. Perhaps the requirements are so complex, there's bound to be a performance hit. A chronjob is almost certainly the wrong answer: it will make the whole design more brittle.

Comment: Yes even i'm scared about cronjob since i have never used it for production yet. Btw my sorry if i couldn't describe my concern.
Scheme is very basic, Let's say one model for transactions (user earn, spend balance) and one for user profile(where i store user current balance, and available balance). Now the only issue is the earn balance can only be available for the user after a specific time to use or withdraw. Now is their any way where i don't have to make query in the whole transaction table to know what's his available balance ?

Comment: Or after that specific days how can i add that current balance into available balance ?

Comment: I'm still not clear on the requirements, but I would consider defining a 'view' that compares transaction date to system date, with the the 'specific time' added in. To optimise, the view can be 'materialized' without upsetting the business logic. OTOH I'm not sure if materializing is allowed with a definition using system date.

Comment: @AntC and that view will be called every hour ? Is that you menat ? But for that we will need cronjob right ?

Comment: Time for you to read the SQL documentation. Or even https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)

Comment: Yeah i can understand it will be a view, but how can i call it ? Even if I have make the view still i need to call it manually ? Because i need to make sure that once the fund get available after specific day for the user, it shows in their account without doing anything manually.